# OKTA Matillion sso 400 Bad request

Tags: single-sign-on, okta, matillion

I am trying to add sso for matillion using okta. I am following below blog. But I am stuck with this error. Is there any way to trouble shoot this. This is my error. Your request resulted in an error. The 'redirect_uri' parameter must be a Login redirect URI in the client app settings. Thanks.
[Intergrationlink](https://documentation.matillion.com/docs/2945146)
I checked other blog for trouble shooting as well but of no help for me.[oktacommunity](https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/The-redirect-uri-parameter-must-be-an-absolute-URI?language=en_US)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the redirect URI for Matillion that you set up in Okta always needs to be something like `https://matillion.mycompany.com/j_security_check`

According to the Okta guides [here](https://devforum.okta.com/t/the-redirect-uri-parameter-must-be-an-absolute-uri-that-is-whitelisted-in-the-client-app-settings/2632/13)
and [here](https://support.okta.com/help/s/article/The-redirect-uri-parameter-must-be-an-absolute-URI?language=en_US)
there are some extra rules
including that

- the URL is case sensitive
- trailing slashes make a difference
- there are no examples of using a dotted IP address so I assume you have to be accessing your Matillion instance with a real DNS name like `https://matillion.mycompany.com` and not `https://11.22.33.44`
- For the same reason I think you have to be on https not http

Comment: I am using http ://matillion.mycompany.com/j_security_check.  So is using http instead of https causing the issue. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Sounds promising.. so did switching to https make the authentication work end to end?